# loop cells to add multiple items to dictionary keys

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a list of duplicate values in column A that will be added as keys to a dictionary. Then for each row in column A there are other duplicates values from column 3 to .columns.count. I need to add them to the dictionary as multiples items of each key. At the end I should have two columns: the first listing all the keys and the second all the items of each keys.
Here my tentative. Could you help find out how to fix it?

```
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LR = .Range("A" & Sheets("Competitor").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


    For thisRow = 2 To LR
     For thiscol = 2 To lc
    'Debug.Print dict.Keys(0)
      If Not dict.Exists(.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value2) And .Cells(thisRow, thiscol).Value2 <> "" Then
      dict.Add .Cells(thisRow, 1).Value2, (.Cells(thisRow, thiscol).Value2)
      Else

      If dict.Exists(.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value2) And .Cells(thisRow, thiscol).Value2 <> "" Then
        dict.Item(.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value2) = .Cells(thisRow, thiscol).Value2
End If
End If
        Next thiscol
        Next thisRow
```

Comment: Use a dictionary with col A as the key and an array() as the item.  Look at `arrays` `ubound` and `redim preserve`  Also, the dic.exists returns true or false, so you just need `if d.exists then... else.... end if` not the 2 if's you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this uses a Dictionary of dictionaries to return unique items for uniqe keys

Option Explicit

```
Sub main()
    Dim iKey As Long
    Dim valsDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set valsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Competitor") ' change "Competitor" to you actual source sheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            If Not valsDict.Exists(cell.value) Then valsDict.Add cell.value, New Scripting.Dictionary
            For Each cell2 In .Range(cell.Offset(, 1), .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                valsDict(cell.value)(cell2.value) = cell2.value
            Next
        Next

        With .Range("AA1") ' change "AA1" with the cell address you want to start writing down data from
            For iKey = 0 To valsDict.Count - 1
                .Offset(iKey).value = valsDict.Keys(iKey)
                .Offset(iKey, 1).Resize(, valsDict.Items(iKey).Count) = valsDict.Items(iKey).Items
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you'd want the resulting list in two columns.  The following code will create a unique list of values from Column A, along with their corresponding values.  The unique values will be listed in one column, and the corresponding values will be concatenated in the next column.  Note that I've assumed that the Sheet1 contains the data, and that the results are to be placed in Sheet2.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateUniqueList()

    Dim oDic As Object
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim arrColIndex As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim thisRow As Long
    Dim thisCol As Long

    Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oDic.CompareMode = 1 'case-insensitive

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ReDim aResults(1 To 2, 1 To LastRow)
        arrColIndex = 0
        For thisRow = 2 To LastRow
            If Len(.Cells(thisRow, "A").Value) > 0 Then
                If Not oDic.Exists(.Cells(thisRow, "A").Value) Then
                    arrColIndex = arrColIndex + 1
                    aResults(1, arrColIndex) = .Cells(thisRow, "A").Value
                    For thisCol = 2 To LastCol
                        aResults(2, arrColIndex) = aResults(2, arrColIndex) & ", " & .Cells(thisRow, thisCol).Value
                    Next thisCol
                    aResults(2, arrColIndex) = Mid(aResults(2, arrColIndex), 3)
                    oDic.Add .Cells(thisRow, "A").Value, arrColIndex
                Else
                    For thisCol = 2 To LastCol
                        aResults(2, oDic(.Cells(thisRow, "A").Value)) = aResults(2, oDic(.Cells(thisRow, "A").Value)) & ", " & .Cells(thisRow, thisCol).Value
                    Next thisCol
                End If
            End If
        Next thisRow
    End With

    If arrColIndex > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve aResults(1 To 2, 1 To arrColIndex)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
            With .Range("A1")
                .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
                .Resize(UBound(aResults, 2), 2).Value = Application.Transpose(aResults)
            End With
            .Activate
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No items found!", vbExclamation
    End If

    Set oDic = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Data**

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
x   1   2   3
y   4   5   6
z   7   8   9

x   10  20  30
y   40  50  60
z   70  80  90
```

**Results**

```
x   1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30
y   4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60
z   7, 8, 9, 70, 80, 90
```

Hope this helps!